# Silveright User Control validation

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, user-controls

I follow MVVM pattern in one of my silverlight pages.
I am trying to add validations for one of my usercontrols which should look like those which work with the Silverlight native controls. Is it possible for me to do that? Do I need to add special code to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

if you could post your code then i might be able to help. But as per your question i think there are available user-validation controls for Silverlight that you can just drag and drop and then use.
They are available in most of the new IDE's.

Comment: Hi, this is for my own created user control. I think Silverfighter's answer points me to the right direction. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ViewModel implements `IDataErrorInfo` and then you can hook them up to the controls.

You can look at a good article here:
http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-idataerrorinfo-for-validation-in-mvvm-with-silverlight-and-wpf/